# linux script as a service within PHP & JS

Tags: php, javascript, linux

Is it possible to create a web application/service in PHP in which the backbone of the application/service is really a linux script and PHP is just relaying the data from the script? The linux script requires certain types of hardware and drivers in order to execute smoothly. I will be hosting the web application and linux script however not the hardware or drivers. I'm thinking of writing up some javascript code that will check if the end-user meet the hardware/driver requirements & have some sort of connection, if so the linux script will execute and utilize the user's hardware to process data that is then passed to PHP. YIKES!? ;o Is my approach for this correct or is there an easier way? Thanks!

Comment: I would like to see a Linux user who would permit a web resource running a shell script on his machine. If it's not a huge commercial secret, what are you trying to achieve this way?

Answer (score 3):

Why even use PHP if its only function is as a conduit to a shell script? Why not just install them as [CGI scripts](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/linux/cgi-scripting-tips-for-bash-or-sh.php)?

You won't be able to check hardware and drivers with Javascript. Having that ability could lead to *huge* security issues. You might, however, be able to write a client-side Java applet that intefaces with the client machine to check out those things for you. However, I don't know enough about Java to know whether or not that's possible (in a client-side applet anyway).